# eclipse: change jre that is used to run ant

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, 32bit-64bit

How do I change the JRE (for example, to go from a from 64bit to 32bit version) that is used to run ant from inside eclipse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure that you can do that in a global way. However, it is possible to choose your JRE when you run `Ant` on a specific project:

Go in the `Properties` of your project, then select `Builders` and `Ant Builder`. In the properties for this builder, go in the `JRE` tab, and choose an `Separate JRE`.

Another solution is to specify the JRE used directly in your `build.xml` file.

Comment: The `Ant Builder` did not exist for me. If so you can do an `Import` and import the `build.xml`.

Answer (score 33):

- From the menu, choose Run -> External Tools -> External Tools Configurations (or use the equivalent toolbar button [image: toolbar button])
- Select your Ant Build
- Click the JRE tab ([image: external tools tabs] ), click Separate JRE and pick the required JRE