# How to set JRE for ANT right in console parameter, not in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ant, console, java

My question is the same, but I do not know how to set another JRE right in ant!
I need to run scripts in console like "path-to-buil-xml/ant"

I do that in Eclipse and I select JRE that I need, but how to set it in console ant?
What the name of parameter?

[eclipse: change jre that is used to run ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041023/eclipse-change-jre-that-is-used-to-run-ant)

I need to build my project in the conditions when I do not have Eclipse.

1. Now I can compile project with Eclipse when I change JRE from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27 to another JRE 1.4.
2. I can do the same without Eclipse but with changing JAVA_HOME to JRE 1.4. But on destination machine I can not change JAVA_HOME, because access denied!

How to do that?

Comment: I need to build my project in the conditions when I do not have Eclipse. 1) Now I can compile project with Eclipse when I change JRE from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27 to another JRE 1.4.   2) I can do the same without Eclipse but with changing JAVA_HOME to JRE 1.4.   But on destination machine I can not change JAVA_HOME, because access denied!  How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the console ant refers to the environment variable JAVA_HOME to find the JRE.

If you don't want to edit the system settings for the windows cmd console use
(this will reset when you close the console)

```
SET JAVA_HOME=PATH_TO_JAVA_HOME
```

You can also set the jdk(via the javac coomand) an argument to the [javac task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html):

```
  <javac srcdir="${src}"
         destdir="${build}"
         fork="yes"
         executable="/opt/java/jdk1.1/bin/javac"
  />
```

#### Side note:

It really needs to be a jdk, if you need to compile.

Comment: I do that in Eclipse, and it named JRE. And all compiled nice. But I need it in console! I do not want to change JAVA_HOME. Because it will be not my computer.

Comment: @Eclipse-user what console are you referring to? The console view in eclipse? or a bash terminal? or a cmd console in windows?

Comment: @eclipse-user so you have to set JAVA_HOME. No way around it. See my updated answer on how to set this value just for the console session.

Comment: OERS, tell me.  I have a trouble just in the following point. My project in Eclipse is building nice. But I need ant script to build my project. Now I wrote ant script and I can compile project, but I need to switch my JRE in properties if I want to have success building....

Comment: ... If I do not change JDK1.6 to JRE1.4, then I meet error. java.sql.PreparedStatement interface is not implemented by my class... But! But I see that in JRE1.4 all implemented fine and eclipse referred me to java.sql.PreparedStatement  of JRE1.4.  I made <classpath> attribut in <javac> attribut that include all files from JRE1.4\jre\lib\   (this is path to files to which eclipse reffered me when I press on this class name)  So... I included it in my classpath, but I meet the same mistake.

Comment: @Eclipse-user another update ... change the javac target in ant, but this is my last try ;D

Comment: I deleted all records in JAVA_HOME and ant build well.  Now I included JAVA_HOME with path to 1.6  and all failed with error above.

Comment: YES, THIS IS SOLUTION:           fork="yes"
         executable="/opt/java/jdk1.1/bin/javac"

Comment: Thanks, bro, from Moscow with love.