# Is there a way to specify which JVM to use for Ant from command line?

Tags: java, linux, ant

My question is pretty much the topic. I'm trying to debug an issue that only occurs on a specific JVM and so I need to build my project with that JVM instead of my default one. I've already consulted `ant --help` but I didn't see anything useful there. So I guess two questions:

1) Is there a way to build ant from the command line using a specific JVM

2) If not, how does `ant` determine what JVM to use? Does it looks directly at `JAVA_HOME` or just look for java on the `PATH`

I'm using Linux just fyi

Comment: for which task ? or for ant itself ?

Comment: Ant itself. In other words, without having to specify it in the buildfile. I'm looking for a command line argument, or maybe an environment variable?

Comment: `$JAVA_HOME` is a good place to start since it points to the latest java installed and this used on your system.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run ant task in different jvm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955486/run-ant-task-in-different-jvm)

Comment: Okay I'll modify that, one question though, is there anyway to determine what java it's using at runtime?

@jgr208 I did actually see that one, but that offered a solution that involved modifying the buildfile which is outside the scope of this question (unfortunately)

Comment: In the console ant refers to the environment variable `$JAVA_HOME` to find the JRE.

Comment: if you look at ant.sh file it has the script how it finds `java`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819109/how-to-set-jre-for-ant-right-in-console-parameter-not-in-eclipse is a good question to look at as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ant` command runs the `java` executable whose path is specified in the `PATH` environment variable, so you need to change that variable in order to use a different JVM.

One way is to create a shell script to do that and run the script:

```
PATH=path_to_you_jdk:$PATH
export PATH

ant
```

Comment: can't you also create ant environment variables as well?

Comment: @jgr208 The OP does not want to change the buildfile.