# required: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, ant, apache-axis

I am trying to import an SVN url on my eclipse.When I tried to run a certain components of the project I keep having this error.

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\phmasu\workspace\CBASServices\branches\CR-XX-SeasonPass\build.xml
init:
pre.compile.test:
     [echo] Stax Availability= true
     [echo] Axis2 Availability= true
compile.src:
    [javac] C:\Users\phmasu\workspace\CBASServices\branches\CR-XX-SeasonPass\build.xml:46: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 630 source files to C:\Users\phmasu\workspace\CBASServices\branches\CR-XX-SeasonPass\build\classes
    [javac] C:\Users\phmasu\workspace\CBASServices\branches\CR-XX-SeasonPass\src\com\cbas\conversion\rule\ConversionType.java:10: incompatible types
    [javac] found   : javax.xml.bind.annotation.AccessType
    [javac] required: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType
    [javac] @XmlAccessorType(AccessType.FIELD)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] C:\Users\phmasu\workspace\CBASServices\branches\CR-XX-SeasonPass\src\com\cbas\conversion\rule\ParameterType.java:9: incompatible types
    [javac] found   : javax.xml.bind.annotation.AccessType
    [javac] required: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType
    [javac] @XmlAccessorType(AccessType.FIELD)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] C:\Users\phmasu\workspace\CBASServices\branches\CR-XX-SeasonPass\src\com\cbas\conversion\rule\CounterType.java:9: incompatible types
    [javac] found   : javax.xml.bind.annotation.AccessType
    [javac] required: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType
    [javac] @XmlAccessorType(AccessType.FIELD)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] C:\Users\phmasu\workspace\CBASServices\branches\CR-XX-SeasonPass\src\com\cbas\conversion\rule\ParameterSetType.java:11: incompatible types
    [javac] found   : javax.xml.bind.annotation.AccessType
    [javac] required: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType
    [javac] @XmlAccessorType(AccessType.FIELD)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] C:\Users\phmasu\workspace\CBASServices\branches\CR-XX-SeasonPass\src\com\cbas\conversion\rule\CounterSetType.java:11: incompatible types
    [javac] found   : javax.xml.bind.annotation.AccessType
    [javac] required: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType
    [javac] @XmlAccessorType(AccessType.FIELD)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] C:\Users\phmasu\workspace\CBASServices\branches\CR-XX-SeasonPass\src\com\cbas\conversion\rule\ConversionsType.java:11: incompatible types
    [javac] found   : javax.xml.bind.annotation.AccessType
    [javac] required: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType
    [javac] @XmlAccessorType(AccessType.FIELD)
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] Note: C:\Users\phmasu\workspace\CBASServices\branches\CR-XX-SeasonPass\src\com\cbas\services\util\PartyUtil.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 6 errors

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\phmasu\workspace\CBASServices\branches\CR-XX-SeasonPass\build.xml:46: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 8 seconds
```

Can someone give me an idea as to where am I doing it wrong? I already put all the necessary library on my lib folder based on the documentation given to me. BTW that project runs on JDK 1.5. I have both JDK 1.6 and 1.5 but I dont know how to configure my Eclipse EE to run it on 1.5. Is that what might cause the problem?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041023/eclipse-change-jre-that-is-used-to-run-ant

Comment: Hi! As you can see I am trying to figure out what might be causing the error. Because im not sure if it is my ANT,Eclipse or Libraries.

Comment: in java 1.6 the `@XmlAccessorType` annotations uses the `XmlAccessType` class as parameter (jaxb2). i guess you'll need to compile the code using java 1.5, and the link above provides you info on how to set the jdk running ant in eclipse

Comment: The JAXB api providing `javax.xml.bind` were updated in late February 2006, having several classes renamed, including AccessType which was renamed to XmlAccessType. You will need to  regenerate your classes with a newer JAXB (if they were generated) or edit them by hand.

Comment: @GUIDO - I have tried that link but it only shows me how to change my JRE on the ant builder.

Btw I have tried a workaround by adding the source and target attributes in <javac> inside my build file. After that, I tried to rebuild the build file using the command line method (Not sure how to rebuild it on Eclipse... It seems that after I made the change on the file its still not working). So far I still have 3 warnings but its working now